# Studies showing positive user reaction when viewing on that the product is made in a country that they consider to have high manufacturing standards?

Tags: user-behavior, perception

Is it favorable, if so how, for a manufacturer to mention that the product is made in a country that is considered to have high standards of manufacturing?

For example, Volkswagen commercials makes an emphasis to mention that their automobiles are made in Germany. How would this translate on the web?

Comment: The seems more of a marketing question than UX.

Comment: Apple puts the emphasis now on *"designed in California"*. This is a little different. Apple is not as much proud of *"made in China"*.

Comment: This also depends on the domain. Germany's reputation for cars, Italy's reputation for pasta. Do the opposite and you get a catastrophe ! ;-)

Comment: @DA01 >Implying that UX is not marketing... Read [why ux is really just good marketing](http://52weeksofux.com/post/461247449/why-ux-is-really-just-good-marketing) and [You ARE a marketer. Deal with it.](http://headrush.typepad.com/creating_passionate_users/2005/08/you_are_a_marke.html)

Comment: @JGallardo context is critical in that distinction. In some companies, there is the ideal where there is a blurred (or even non-existent) line between the two. However, reality is that in many companies there's a rather hard line--and sometimes even a wall between the two. Regardless the question tends to be market-research related. We can certainly put it into a UX bucket. I was merely pointing out that this is typically (right or wrong) the domain of the marketing team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a product is from a country which is perceived to make quality products, people may make the assumption that it is also of high quality. It is known as the **country-of-origin effect**.

> The country-of-origin effect (COE) is a psychological effect which
>   occurs when customers are unfamiliar with a product (e.g., product
>   quality) and the image of the product's country of origin has a "halo
>   effect" on the customers' evaluation of the product.

**Source:** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country-of-origin_effect

Some companies make great effort to make their products country of origin known, going as far as to **make it clear in their branding**. Swiss companies are especially known for this:

[image]

**The country of origin can also have an opposite effect.** Products from countries that aren't known for producing high quality goods can sometimes be mistakenly assumed to be an inferior product. This is known as the **provenance paradox**.

> A product’s country of origin establishes its authenticity. Consumers
>   associate certain geographies with the best products: French wine,
>   Italian sports cars, Swiss watches. Competing products from other
>   countries—especially developing markets—are perceived as less
>   authentic. Even when their quality is on par with that of established
>   players, the developing-market firms can’t command a fair price. The
>   lower price, in turn, reinforces the idea that the offering isn’t as
>   good and that the region doesn’t make premium products.

**Source:** http://hbr.org/2010/12/why-you-arent-buying-venezuelan-chocolate/